# I want to compare two comma delimited strings in PHP and keep only the values that appear in both

Tags: php, string

I have two comma delimited strings with integers. One is the IDs of article types that a script being called is told to display (by POST) and the other is the IDs of article types the current logged in user actually has permission to see.

I want to generate a third comma separated list of integers with the values that appear in both. e.g.:

```
$want_to_see = "1,5,6,8,10"

$current_user_can_see = "1,3,6,10,20"

$show = "1,6,10"
```

Comment: Use `explode` to turn them into arrays, `array_intersect` to get the common elements, and `implode` to turn it back into a string.

Comment: I hope that's enough for you. I'm not going to write a real answer, it's too trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I realised precisely that after writing my question. I'll put the code in the answer in case someone finds it useful, trivial as it may seem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break the two strings into arrays using [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), and then use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to keep only the common values:

```
$want_to_see = explode(",", "1,5,6,8,10");
$current_user_can_see = explode(",", "1,3,6,10,20")

// Array of common elements:
$show = array_intersect($want_to_see, $current_user_can_see);

// If you want it as a string:
$show_str = implode(",", $show);
```